# Dependency to a npm package in a cordova plugin not working

Tags: cordova

I have a cordova plugin with a js file that depends on a js module (phg-js-baseplate) installed via npm.

When testing locally the module loads fine, but when the apk is installed it fails because "Uncaught module phg-js-baseplate not found".

**Relevant scripts**

In my plugin.xml I include a js file:

```
  <js-module src="www/baseplate_piping.js" name="BaseplatePiping">
    <clobbers target="baseplate" />
  </js-module>
```

In the js file (baseplate_piping.js) I include a js module:

```
const jsbaseplate = require('phg-js-baseplate')
```

In package.json I include the module:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "phg-js-baseplate": "0.0.2"
  }
```

When running local tests, the module is included just fine. But when the APK starts I get this error:

```
D SERVER  : Handling local request: http://localhost/4.036b30ba13cf10109bec.js
D SERVER  : Handling local request: http://localhost/17.4dba627aeecfd53a0a15.js
D SERVER  : Handling local request: http://localhost/16.26cbb78e9813619b0273.js
D SERVER  : Handling local request: http://localhost/35.6872ffdc3d6c9f24e10f.js
D SERVER  : Handling local request: http://localhost/75.9987b2793d8c60c3c201.js
D SystemWebChromeClient: http://localhost/polyfills.ff5a64219439259f93cc.js: Line 1 : Uncaught module phg-js-baseplate not found
```

I would expect the module to be found just fine, since it is declared in package.json.

Do I need to tell cordova that it should bundle the dependencies in package.json or could something along those lines.

Thanks,
Jesper